# IndexError: list index out of range when using lists Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

Good day Friends, I'm doing an exercise in python of numerical methods, ordinary differential equations and you are giving me a list index out of range error, if anyone can lend me a hand I would appreciate it very much

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
def fun(x,y):
    return x**2/(1 +y**2)

"""#Runge-Kutta 1er orden
$y_(i+1)   =     y_i+  f(x_i,y_i )*h$
"""

def runge_kutta_1(f,a,b,h,y0): #función,inicial,final,tamaño de paso y y0
    x=[]
    y=[]
    x.append(a)
    y.append(y0)
    while x[0]<b:
        y.append(y[3]+f(x[0],y[3])*h)
        x.append(x[0] + h)
        return x,y

"""#Runge-Kutta 2do orden
$y_(i+1) = y_i+(1/3k1+2/3k2)*h$
"""

def runge_kutta_2(f,a,b,h,y0):
    x=[]
    y=[]
    x.append(a)
    y.append(y0)
    while x[0]<b:
        k1=f(x[0],y[3])
        k2=f(x[0]+3/4*h,y[3]+3/4*k1*h)
        y.append(y[3]+(1/3*k1+2/3*k2)*h)
        x.append(x[0]+h)
    return x,y

"""# Runge-Kutta 4to orden

$y_(i+1) =  y_i+1/6(k1+2k2+2k3+k4)*h$
"""

def runge_kutta_4(f,a,b,h,y0): 
    x=[]
    y=[]
    x.append(a)
    y.append(y0)
    while x[0]<b:
        k1=f(x[0],y[3])
        k2=f(x[0]+0.5*h,y[3]+0.5*k1*h)
        k3=f(x[0]+0.5*h,y[3]+0.5*k2*h)
        k4=f(x[0]+h,y[3]+k3*h)
        y.append(y[3]+(h/6)*(k1 +2*k2+2*k3+k4))
        x.append(x[0]+h)
    return x,y

h=0.5
print("tamaño de paso(0.5): ",h)
x1,y1=runge_kutta_1(fun,0,5,h,3)
x2,y2=runge_kutta_2(fun,0,5,h,3)
x4,y4=runge_kutta_4(fun,0,5,h,3)
x5=np.arange(0,5,0.01)
y5= y**3/3 + y - x**3/3                   #Solución analítica de la ED
 
# Gráfica
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10), dpi=80) # Tamaño de la gráfica
plt.plot(x1,y1,label="RK 1er orden")
plt.plot(x2,y2,label="RK 2do orden")
plt.plot(x4,y4,label="RK 4to orden")
plt.plot(x5,y5,label="Solución Real")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I get error **on line 58 in x1,y1=runge_kutta_1(fun,0,5,h,3)**
**line 17, in runge_kutta_1 y.append(y +f(x,y)*h) IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: Look at `runge_kutta_1`.  At the top of the function, it sets both `x` and `y` to `[]`, so at that point they both have length zero.  It then appends a single value to each of them, so at that point they both have length 1.  
Then it enters the loop, and it tries to access `y[3]`.  If `y` has length 1, then the only valid index for `y` is 0.  So you are indexing out of bounds, exactly as it told you.  You can fix it by appending more values to `y`, or changing `y[3]` to `y[0]`.  I doubt either will do what you want, so you need to figure out what you want, and fix it.

Comment: In general, when you get an error that says "list index out of range", it means exactly what it says:  You're indexing into something, and your index is out of range.  So all you need to do is look at all of the indices on the indicated line, and figure out which one is out of range.  Add a debugging statement if you need to.  It's something you can easily do on your own.

Comment: Basically you are trying to access an index on list *y* that does not exist. Initially you only have `x = [0]` and `y  = [3]`

Answer (score 0):

You should once more contemplate the index order. You compute the next step from the values obtained in the previous step, so you need to use the last element in the lists. (Use local variables to avoid to repeatedly access the same array element.)

For the RK2 method your code would need to be changed to

```
def runge_kutta_2(f,a,b,h,y0):
    x=[a]
    y=[y0]
    while x[-1]<b:
        k1=f(x[-1],y[-1])
        k2=f(x[-1]+3/4*h,y[-1]+3/4*k1*h)
        y.append(y[-1]+(1/3*k1+2/3*k2)*h)
        x.append(x[-1]+h)
    return x,y
```

Be sure to take into account that the last element of the `x` array will rarely be equal or very close to `b`.

Comment: Thanks my friend in really by the solution